# Search the table of strings with each character

Tags: string, macos, sqlite, data-structures

I am stuck at a problem with strings. I have many (lets say more 100) two dimensional arrays with strings. I will need to search through them for occurrence of a match string (entered through a search bar). If any occurrence, the row containing the matched string have to be displayed in a table view. With each entered character in the search bar, the results must be refined and displayed in a table view.

All the strings data must be saved and must be opened for later use. Could any one please suggest on the following things?

1. Is it fine saving all the two dimensional arrays of strings in a database.(SQLite)? or each array in an xml file? or any other better idea?
2. How to search efficiently through the all the strings? I am thinking to create a trie data structure for better searching.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand question 1. Yes, both of those are reasonable options. Or you could just save them to a flat file, too. Without more info, it's hard to tell you what the right way to save them is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to mention that the strings data is very huge in each 2*2 dimensional array which just looks like a table with many rows and columns. Please let me know which other information do you need in this case.

Comment: How about this - how big is the average string in your data? How big is the average 2 dimensional array? How many 2 dimensional arrays do you have? (I guess the last one is "more than 100", but is it less than 1000?) I'm just trying to understand the order of magnitude of your data, but I think I'm making some incorrect assumptions based on what you've written so far.

Comment: The max length of string can be 256 characters. The max size of a two dim array can be up to 20000 * 5 which means 20,000 rows and 5 columns. And the number of arrays can be up to 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have up to 20,000,000 strings, I wouldn't advise using XML for your file format. It will add a lot of overhead both in disk space and parsing time. A database definitely sounds like a better way to go to me. If the strings were all the max length, that would be 5GB of data just for the strings, so you might even want to compress them in some way, depending on the end user's machine.

A trie also sounds like a good choice of data structure for searching through them. Though, it will be pretty big. It might not need to be the whole 5GB in memory, but with the various pointers and stuff needed to implement it, it will likely still be quite large. How large probably depends on the amount of overlap between the strings' prefixes. You could use a [compact prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_prefix_tree) if the data proves too large.

Another option would be to sort them all and do a binary search as the user types. It would probably not be efficient to sort them on the fly, though, so you'd probably want to save a pre-sorted index of the strings. (Not sure if you can do that, or if the data changes while running the app.)

Comment: I d go with SQLite database to save the strings data on the disk. And either trie or compact prefix tree to perform the searches. How do you think about the performance if I implement this in a mac osx application ?